# Connect Exception while connecting with printer

Tags: printing, lan, cups, network-printers

### I am using cups printer and using mdns service to connect with the printer i have on the same lan but i am not able to connect with the printer and its throwing the exception

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /fe80::cad3:ffff:feb0:c01b (port 631) after 10000ms: connect failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

if anyone have ever worked on it please help me stuck on this issue since last 2 days.

Comment: I have also encountered the same issue.

Comment: Let me know if any one found any solution.